# find average daily balance for the last 1 year for an account where no rows exists for dates in between

Tags: sql, oracle

Account table details are as below:

AcctNbr
BalAmt
BalChgDate



111
    50
        04/01/2021



111
    70
    05/01/2021



111
    100
    06/01/2021



111
    40
    07/01/2021



111
    30
    07/07/2021

I can find the average daily balance by finding the ending balance for each day like below:

AcctNbr
BalAmt
BalChgDate



111
    50
        04/01/2021



111
    50
        04/02/2021



111
    50
        04/03/2021


 
---------------------------------------------------



111
    50
        04/30/2021



111
    70
    05/01/2021



111
    70
        05/02/2021



 ---------------------------------------------------



111
    70
        05/31/2021




111
    100
    06/01/2021



 ---------------------------------------------------



111
    40
    07/01/2021



 ---------------------------------------------------



111
    30
    07/07/2021

I am thinking of using connect by to get all the 365 days in a subquery and then making a left join of this subquery with above table. Then after this I am not able to figure how to use window function to get the average daily balance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
WITH date_range (start_date, end_date) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2021-04-01', ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2021-04-01', 12) FROM DUAL
),
balances_within_range (acctnbr, balamt, balchgdate, range_end) AS (
  -- Prior value
  SELECT acctnbr,
         COALESCE(MAX(balamt) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY t.balchgdate), 0),
         d.start_date,
         d.end_date
  FROM   table_name t
         INNER JOIN date_range d
         ON (t.balchgdate <= d.start_date)
  GROUP BY t.acctnbr, d.start_date, d.end_date
UNION ALL
  -- Changes within range
  SELECT acctnbr,
         balamt,
         balchgdate,
         d.end_date
  FROM   table_name t
         INNER JOIN date_range d
         ON (d.start_date <= t.BalChgDate AND t.BalChgDate < d.end_date)
),
balance_ranges (acctnbr, balamt, balchgdate, nextchgdate) AS (
  SELECT AcctNbr,
         BalAmt,
         BalChgDate,
         LEAD(BalChgDate, 1, range_end)
           OVER (PARTITION BY AcctNbr ORDER BY BalChgDate)
  FROM   balances_within_range
)
SELECT acctnbr,
       ROUND(
         SUM(balamt * (nextchgdate - balchgdate))
           / SUM(nextchgdate - balchgdate),
         2
       ) AS avg_daily_balance
FROM   balance_ranges
GROUP BY acctnbr
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (AcctNbr, BalAmt, BalChgDate) AS
SELECT 111,  50, DATE '2021-04-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111,  70, DATE '2021-05-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111, 100, DATE '2021-06-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111,  40, DATE '2021-07-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 111,  30, DATE '2021-07-07' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ACCTNBR | AVG_DAILY_BALANCE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 111 | 40.96 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=673e9ab41428fb0cddb276c4af077419)*

Answer (score 0):

Didn't quite got the daily calc for July month where amount gets changed.
Below is based on last value for a day in a given month within a year.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2669c07edb4522863ed68073c53f1cea)

```
with date_cte (balance_dt) as 
(
select to_date('01-JAN-2021','DD-MON-YYYY') + level-1 from dual connect by level<366
), acct_bal_cte(AcctNbr,BalAmt,BalChgDate) as
(
select 111,50,to_date('04/01/2021','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
select 111,70,to_date('05/01/2021','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
select 111,100,to_date('06/01/2021','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
select 111,40,to_date('07/01/2021','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all
select 111,30,to_date('07/07/2021','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
), rn_cte as 
(
select a.*, row_number() over (partition by extract(month from a.BalChgDate) 
    order by a.BalChgDate) rn from acct_bal_cte a), cte_a as
(
select b.balance_dt balance_dt, a.rn from  rn_cte a, date_cte b
where extract(month from a.BalChgDate) = extract(month from b.balance_dt)
and extract(day from a.BalChgDate) <= extract(day from b.balance_dt)
), cte_b as
(
select balance_dt, max(rn) rn from cte_a group by balance_dt order by rn,balance_dt
)
select a.AcctNbr,a.BalAmt,b.balance_dt from rn_cte a, cte_b b
where extract(month from a.BalChgDate) = extract(month from b.balance_dt)
and a.rn = b.rn
order by b.balance_dt
```